# Пути ускорения чтения данных для матриц из файла(.txt) и последующего перемножения матриц

Tags: java, инспекция-кода, производительность, матрицы

1. Имеется.
   txt файл следующего вида:

3 2
1 2

1 2
2 4

4 2
1 3

1 2
2 1

Где первые 4 цифры:
3 -количество матриц в файле (любое число не более 130)
2 -размер матриц (они всегда квадратные, любой размер не более 130)
1, 2 -i, j искомого элемента результирующей матрицы
Все остальные числа ниже -это сами матрицы:

1 2 матрица 1
3 4

4 2 матрица 2
1 3

1 2 матрица 3
2 1

2. Нужно сделать.
   В результате нужно вывести в файл число из результирующей матрицы с координатами по строке и столбцу указанными в файле (1, 2 в приведенном примере).
   Результирующая матрица-это матрица полученная перемножением матриц из файла.
   В приведенном случае ответ: 20

Мой код:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by Pazuk on 28.01.2018.
 */

// Main idea:
// Step 1. Get all values from input file and according with it build array with numbers for matrices
// Step 2.
// Loop iteration:
// - get numbers from array and create next matrix array
// - multiply actual matrix with next matrix, get result matrix
// - mark result matrix as actual matrix
// Next iteration...
// Step 3. After last iteration, get from result matrix requested number (positions specified in input file)


public class Main {    

    static int[] list;

    static boolean fileCheckOk=true;
    static int m;
    static int n;
    static int a;
    static int b;        

    static int[][] matrixA;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println(time);

        readFile();

        time = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
        System.out.println(time);

        if(fileCheckOk){
            calculate();

            PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter("output.txt");
            writer.print(matrixA[a-1][b-1]);
            writer.close();
        }

        time = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
        System.out.println(time);
    }

    static void readFile() throws IOException {

        StreamTokenizer tokenizer=new StreamTokenizer(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));    

        //general input values:
        tokenizer.nextToken();
        m=(int)tokenizer.nval; // number of matricis
        tokenizer.nextToken();
        n=(int)tokenizer.nval; // matrices size
        tokenizer.nextToken();
        a=(int)tokenizer.nval; // position i of requested number
        tokenizer.nextToken();
        b=(int)tokenizer.nval; // position j of requested number                

        list=new int[m*n*n]; // array length according with quantity of matricis and their size
        int i=0;
        while(tokenizer.nextToken()!=StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){
            list[i]=(int)tokenizer.nval;
            i++;
        } 

        /*if(m>=1 && m<=130 && n>=1 && n<=130 && a>=1 && a<=n && b>=1 && b<=n){
            fileCheckOk=true; //check if input values are comply with task conditions

        }*/
    }       

    static void calculate(){ // calculate matrices

        int f, i, j, k;
        int r=0;
        int t;
        int temp;
        int[] thatColumn=new int[n];
        int[] thisRow=new int[n];
        int result=0;

        matrixA=new int[n][n]; // actual matrix
        for(f=0; f< m; f++){ // number of iterations==matrices quantity
            int[][] matrixB=new int[Main.n][Main.n]; // next matrix
            for(i=0; i< Main.n; i++){
                for(j=0; j< Main.n; j++){
                    matrixB[i][j]=list[r];
                    r++;
                }
            }

            if(f>0){
                int[][] matrixC=new int[Main.n][Main.n]; //result matrix

                for(j=0; j< Main.n; j++){
                    for(k=0; k< Main.n; k++){
                        thatColumn[k]=matrixB[k][j];
                    }

                    for(i=0; i< Main.n; i++){
                        thisRow=matrixA[i];
                        result=0;
                        for(k=0; k<Main.n; k++){
                            temp=thisRow[k]*thatColumn[k];
                            result=result+temp;                           
                        }
                         matrixC[i][j]=result;
                    }
                }

                /*for(i=0; i< Main.n; i++){
                    for(j=0; j< Main.n; j++){
                        t=matrixA[i][k];
                        for(j=0; j< Main.n; j++){
                            temp=t*matrixB[k][j]; // multiplying...                                
                            matrixC[i][j]=matrixC[i][j]+temp; // ...matrces
                        }
                    }
                }*/

                matrixA=matrixC;                    
            } else {
                matrixA=matrixB;                    
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Код работает и выдает правильный ответ. Но не проходит тесты из-за слишком медленной работы. Какие могут быть пути ускорения?

1 Может быть другой внутренний алгоритм перемножения матриц? Сейчас они перемножаются "в лоб":

```
for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
             for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                 for(int k=0; k<o; k++){
                     resultMatrix[i][j]+=mA[i][k]*mB[k][j]; 
                 }
             }
         }
```

Ну, почти так. Немного быстрее (см. метод calculate).

2 Может быть разбить вычисления по отдельным потокам?

3 Может быть другой путь обработки данных файла?
Сейчас каждое последующее целое число файла, первые 4 присваиваем переменным, все остальные-загоняем в одномерный массив. Из которого потом берем значения для создания матриц, которые перемножаются.

Как-то так.

Comment: попробуйте решение со `StreamTokenizer` из http://acm.timus.ru/help.aspx?topic=java

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Воспользовался StreamTokenizer. Замеры времени исполнения кода показывают, что скорость чтения данных из файла намного увеличилась. Однако код по-прежнему не проходит, валясь на все том же тесте из-за превышения time limit. Исходя из этого, предполагаю, что способ чтения данных фала как таковой из подозреваемых в причине непрохождения кода на скорость можно исключить.

Comment: попробуйте все-таки как в инструкции с заворачиванием в `BufferedReader` (`new StreamTokenizer(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));`)

Comment: Попробовал. Результат тот же.